# Proc Import. Importing Character values as "Blank" from excel files

Tags: import, sas

I am trying to import multiple excel files using the code below. There is a column in each excel file that has both numeric and text values but proc import is only importing numeric values, and put the text values as blank ('.').

Can anyone help with me this issue? Thanks much.

```
%let subdir=S:\Temp\;  

filename dir "&subdir.*.xls";

data new;

length filename  fname $ 32767;

infile dir  eof=last filename=fname;

input ;

last: filename=fname; 

run; 

proc sort data=new nodupkey;

by filename;

run;

data null;

set new end=last;

call symputx(cats('filename',_n_),filename);

call symputx(cats('dsn',_n_),scan(scan(filename,7,'\'),1,'.'));

if last then call symputx('nobs',_n_);

run;

%put &nobs;

%macro import;

%do i=1 %to &nobs;


proc import datafile="&&filename&i" out=&&dsn&i 

dbms=excel replace;

sheet = "Sheet1";

getnames=yes;

mixed=yes;

run;


%end;

%mend import;

%import
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to control the data types in an imported Excel work book is to use the `DBSASTYPE` data set option with a libname.  This is especially useful when dealing with other data types (like datetime and time values).

For example, let's assume that the affected column is named **MY_VAR** and should always be read as character with a max length of 30.  And let's also assume you have a spreadsheet column named **START_TIME** that contains an Excel coded date and time stamp. Your macro might be revised like this:

```
libname x "&&filename&i";
data &&dsn&i;
   set x.'Sheet1$'n(dbsastype=(MY_VAR=char30 START_TIME=datetime));
run;
libname x clear;
```

As long as you know the name of the Excel column causing the problem, this should work well.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I am still getting the character values as blanks in the SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed=Yes should fix things for you, but if it's not, then there are a few solutions.

First off, you may want to check your scan value.  You can see one possible location here:
http://support.sas.com/kb/35/563.html

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ► Software ► Microsoft ► Office ► 12.0 ► Access Connectivity Engine ► Engines

If you have an older version of office (pre-2007), it's called the "JET Engine" and is located in a slightly different place (you can google for it).  Your "12.0" may be different depending on what you have installed (12.0 is Office 2007).

Second, you can force columns to be particular types. DBSASTYPE option is where you need to go for this; see http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/020-31.pdf for example (about in the middle of the document, search for DBSASTYPE).